# undefined method `reset_default_attributes!' for class ARUnit2Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got this error when running `rake test:mysql2` in `rails/rails` repository.

```
/Users/dorianmariefr/src/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing': undefined method `reset_default_attributes!' for class ARUnit2Model (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  reset_default_attributes
    from /Users/dorianmariefr/src/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/attributes.rb:267:in `reload_schema_from_cache'
    from /Users/dorianmariefr/src/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:86:in `reload_schema_from_cache'
    from /Users/dorianmariefr/src/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/attributes.rb:292:in `reset_default_attributes'
    from /Users/dorianmariefr/src/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/attributes.rb:6:in `reload_schema_from_cache'
    from <internal:kernel>:187:in `loop'
    from <internal:prelude>:5:in `irb'
    from /Users/dorianmariefr/src/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/attributes.rb:266:in `reload_schema_from_cache'
    from /Users/dorianmariefr/src/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:86:in `reload_schema_from_cache'
    from /Users/dorianmariefr/src/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:568:in `inherited'
    from /Users/dorianmariefr/src/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:286:in `inherited'
    from /Users/dorianmariefr/src/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb:195:in `inherited'
    from /Users/dorianmariefr/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/activemodel-7.1.2/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:381:in `inherited'
    from /Users/dorianmariefr/src/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:262:in `inherited'
    from /Users/dorianmariefr/src/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/primary_key.rb:147:in `inherited'
    from /Users/dorianmariefr/src/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:136:in `inherited'
    from /Users/dorianmariefr/src/rails/activerecord/test/models/arunit2_model.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    ... 19 levels...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do:

```
>> Object.const_source_location('ActiveModel::AttributeRegistration')
=> 
["/Users/dorianmariefr/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/activemodel-7.1.2/lib/active_model/attribute_registration.rb",
```

So it's loading the rails gem from my gems instead of from the repository.

Solution is to `bundle clean --force`

Comment: I am not sure this explains why this is a solution to the problem. Additionally all gems will be loaded from your gems directory as bundle install does just as it states and installs the gem locally.